# Couldnt print out the Hexadecimal value of the string

Tags: python, hex, ascii

```
   string = "Karma police, arrest this man, he talks in maths"  
   byte_string = string.encode("utf-8")
   hex_string = byte_string.hex()
   print("Hex: ".format(hex_string))
```

I am trying to print out the hexadecimal value of the string, but the output is empty

> ouput-> Hex:

What should I change in order to print out the hexadecimal value?

Comment: `print('Hex:', hex_string)`?

Comment: You need to provide a placeholder in your format string to tell it where to put the value of the variable. Please read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 2):

You forgot placeholder for `.format()`

```py
string = "Karma police, arrest this man, he talks in maths"  
byte_string = string.encode("utf-8")
hex_string = byte_string.hex()
print("Hex: {}".format(hex_string))
```

Comment: Forgetting the placeholder wouldn't have happened with an f-string: `print(f'Hex: {hex_string}')`